# How to properly measure svg group dimensions in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, svg, graph, tensorboard

I am trying to build a tool with the help of Angular to visualize graphs similar to TensorBoard. My intention is to visualize the dependency graph that the build tool bazel outputs. In order to highlight the graph I want to draw a rect as a background. My current approach is to draw the nodes and edges within one group, measure the dimensions of the group and set the width and height of the rect accordingly. If I change the graph structure by expanding or minimizing a node the background rect does not update properly. I am guessing that this is because no change was made with respect to the components data and therefore the view won't get updated by Angular.

You will find the source code here: https://github.com/dprogm/graph-explorer

The template of the graph looks like this:

```
<svg:rect
  attr.width="{{_graph.width}}"
  attr.height="{{_graph.height}}" />

<svg:g #graphRef>
  <svg:path  *ngFor="let edge of _graph.edges"
    class="edge"
    [attr.d]="buildPath(edge)" />

  <svg:g app-graph-node *ngFor="let node of _graph.nodes"
    [node]="node"
    (nodeChange)="onNodeChanged($event)"></svg:g>
</svg:g>
```

The `#graphRef` is an `ElementRef` which is used for querying the bounding box:

```
if(this.graphRef !== undefined) {
  let graphBBox = this.graphRef.nativeElement.getBBox();
  this._graph.width = graphBBox.width;
  this._graph.height = graphBBox.height;
}
```

The main question is: Is there any better approach of measuring the size of the graph and if not  how can I achieve that I get the right dimensions?

[image: Before minimizing the subgraph node]

[image: After minimizing the subgraph node]

You can reproduce the issue here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mkmkm6?file=src/app/app.component.html
If you click the circle it changes the size. I want that the black rect also changes its size to fit the circle.

Comment: It's going to pretty hard for a casual viewer to investigate the issue without a (simple) running example. Can you put together an [mcve]?

Comment: I have added a minimal example that should illustrate my problem. The main problem is that I have to measure the dimensions of the group (that contains the circle) because I can not calculate them in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `requestAnimationFrame()`:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  {

  // Background width
  bgWidth = 0;
  // Background height
  bgHeight = 0;
  // Radius of the circle
  r = 100;
  // Stroke width of the circle
  strokeWidth = 5;
  // Whether to draw a large or small circle
  largeMode: Boolean = true;

  @ViewChild('groupRef')
  groupRef : ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    requestAnimationFrame(()=> this.setRectSize());
  }

  setRectSize(): void {
    let groupBBox = this.groupRef.nativeElement.getBBox();
    this.bgWidth = groupBBox.width;
    this.bgHeight = groupBBox.height;
  }

  changeSize() : void {
    this.largeMode = !this.largeMode;
    if(this.largeMode) {
      this.r = 100;
    } else {
      this.r = 50;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(()=> this.setRectSize());
  }
}
```